# Git commits via RStudio always creates/merges branches on TFS

Tags: r, git, visual-studio, tfs, rstudio

I have two users sharing R code on a TFS Server.  One user is in RStudio (v1.0.143), the other in Visual Studio 2015.

When I look at the code history, it looks like the RStudio user is always doing two commits instead of one:  the first is the legitimate commit, and the second looks like a merging of branches, with the comment "Merge branch 'master' of ..."

How do I stop this constant branch-and-merge?  Is there a way RStudio can just do regular commits?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I suspect this may be a TFS thing.  It sounds like the R user is always merging, and that Git is creating a superfluous merge commit with each merge, which you don't want.  Check the Git/TFS settings is probably the way to fix this.

Comment: what is the other side of the merge, does it contain anything?

Comment: @max630 The "merge" seems to attribute all un-pulled changes to the user.  I guess the solution (as listed below) is to make sure my RStudio user always does a pull before a push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behavior of git when there's at least one commit locally that is not in the remote (and vice versa) when the push occurs. Git creates a merge commit to combine the branches that have diverged.

You might ask your RStudio user to perform a pull immediately before they make their commit, and to perform a push immediately after, so that they don't wind up with a divergent branch.

In git parlance, what you want is for the RStudio user to be able to do a [fast-forward merge](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/git-fast-forwards-and-branch-management-329977726.html) when pushing changes. Hope that helps!